# Linking css styles

Tags: css

How can I do something like this in CSS:

```
#red-button {
    .red
}

#green-button {
    .green
}

.red {
    background: red;
}

.green {
    background: green;
}
```

I have seen this done before but I can't seem to recall how.

Comment: You could have a look at LESS (http://lesscss.org/) These things are called "dynamic stylesheets". There are alternatives to LESS but cant remember. Well have a look at google. However, nettuts.com has a few tutorials about LESS and will explain you all you need to use these things in CSS. Bauce it takes a bit of work to get that working. Actually as far as I am concerned for LESS you need ruby...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`LESS`](http://lesscss.org/) (and other similar solutions there) for that.

> LESS extends CSS with dynamic behavior such as variables, mixins,
>   operations and functions. LESS runs on both the client-side (IE 6+,
>   Webkit, Firefox) and server-side, with Node.js.

There is also [`SASS`](http://sass-lang.com/) you can use.

> Sass makes CSS fun again. Sass is an extension of CSS3, adding nested
>   rules, variables, mixins, selector inheritance, and more. It’s
>   translated to well-formatted, standard CSS using the command line tool
>   or a web-framework plugin.

Comment: +1, didn't know LESS/SASS. Though a simpler solution is better.